# Fastest way to get a not required specific record in database using Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-queryset

What would be the fastest way to get a specific record, that can or cannot exists, using Django.

Some possible approaches:

```
results = ModelExample.objects.filter(label="example1")
if(results.exists())
   item = results.first()

results = ModelExample.objects.filter(label="example1")
if(len(results) > 0)
   item = results.first()
```

## *** Edit ***

I was not clear on my original question, my real search is to a way to get a property from a nullable object return from a queryset, case the object exists, take the property and if does not return None.

I was looking for something similar to item?.value on JavaScript.

Fortunately @Willem help me showing the **getattr(...)** function on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `.first()`. If the item does not exists, it will return `None`, so:

```
result = ModelExample.objects.filter(label='example1').first()
if result is None:
    # does not exists
    # …
    pass
```

you can make use of a one-liner to obtain a property with:

```
result = getattr(
    ModelExample.objects.filter(label='example1').first(),
    'name-of-the-attribute',
    None
)
```

Comment: It has a pretty way to get a property from this item, case exists, in one single line? And if does not exists return None.. something similar to item?.value on JavaScript

Comment: @PatrickFreitas: you can work with `getattr(...)`. If the attribute does not exists, then it will here return `None`.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what i was looking for, i was tired from verify the existence of an object in multiple lines over and over again. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

item = ModelExample.objects.filter(label="example1").first()

.first() "Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is no matching object."

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/